# Running Test cases sequentially in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to know how I can run test cases sequentially in a test suite. 
For an example, loading a URL, login to the system etc.

Comment: could you be a little more specific? do you mean you want to execute describes and its in a certain order? because if so that already happens it goes from top to bottom, or do you mean the script within each it block? have you looked at the protractor documentation?

Comment: I have wrote it methods in one spec file.. I want to take them out into several files and execute them in a sequence.

Answer (score 14):

Check the [protractor.conf.js example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/58197ea68cfdf89771ad326457669e68f8add571/example/conf.js#L10-L12).

You could specify a glob that will load files in alphabetical order, or pass a list that forces sequential execution in the order you specify.

```
specs: [
    'test/stories/login.js',
    'test/stories/home/overview.js',
    'test/stories/home/purchase/widget.js'
],
```

and so on. I would not recommend forcing tests to execute in an exact order *between spec files*, since this means you'll have a hard time isolating just certain parts of tests later when they break. You'll be forced to always run the whole suite every time.

Comment: i agree with this answer, writing tests so they have to be executed in a certain is a real pain, its something i did when i first started automating and i'm now having to go back to make sure all my tests can be run in isolation. obviously some tests do need to be done first (ie. login tests) but you are able to put tests in the onPrepare in the conf.js file, the onPrepare can also reference a different file, so if you have a load of things you need to run on test start up every time you don't clog your conf file up. that would look like this `onPrepare: '../startup/startup.js'`

Comment: Thanks :) And I did it like this. Using the report generator makes me realize that they run sequentially. :) Cheers